# Why getlocationonscreen returining -180 for x?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using the google vision library (although this might not matter for the purpose of this question). Here is the xml file

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/topLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true">

    <com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.ocrreader.ui.camera.CameraSourcePreview
        android:id="@+id/preview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.ocrreader.ui.camera.GraphicOverlay
            android:id="@+id/graphicOverlay"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.ocrreader.ui.camera.CameraSourcePreview>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now if do

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    int  [] loc = new int[2];
    mPreview.getLocationOnScreen(loc);
    int  [] loc2 = new int[2];
    mGraphicOverlay.getLocationOnScreen(loc2);
}
```

Then loc1 is {0,0} which is expected but loc2 is{-180,0}.

Why is that? Shouldn't it be also 0,0?
Thank you

Here is the UI part from dympsys

```
  View Hierarchy:
          DecorView@55587bd[OcrLiveActivity]
            android.widget.LinearLayout{d743bae V.E...... ........ 0,0-1080,1920}
              android.view.ViewStub{b409d4f G.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #1020471 android:id/action_mode_bar_stub}
              android.widget.FrameLayout{48b3cdc V.E...... ........ 0,0-1080,1920}
                android.support.v7.widget.FitWindowsLinearLayout{9fc21e5 V.E...... ........ 0,0-1080,1920 #7f08000b app:id/action_bar_root}
                  android.support.v7.widget.ViewStubCompat{ecc64ba G.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f080017 app:id/action_mode_bar_stub}
                  android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout{593bf6b V.E...... ........ 0,0-1080,1920 #1020002 android:id/content}
                    android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout{bfd4ac8 V.E...... ........ 0,0-1080,1920 #7f0800d6 app:id/topLayout} 

com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.ocrreader.ui.camera.CameraSourcePreview{651f761 V.E...... ........ 0,0-1080,1920 #7f080091 app:id/preview}
                        android.view.SurfaceView{4c1286 V.E...... ........ -180,0-1260,1920}               

com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.ocrreader.ui.camera.GraphicOverlay{7ace747 V.ED..... ........ -180,0-1260,1920 #7f080058 app:id/graphicOverlay}
```

Comment: whats the output of `adb shell dumpsys activity top`? (only UI tree part)

Comment: Never tried that. Let me try it and send it to you

Comment: @pskink what do you think

Comment: `CameraSourcePreview` (app:id/preview) bounds are `0,0-1080,1920` (width 1080) while `SurfaceView` width is 1440 so its calculated bounds are `-180,0-1260,1920` - the same bounds are set for `GraphicOverlay` (app:id/graphicOverlay)

Comment: ohhh I see. I wonder why is it bigger. I gotta look more into this sample google code

Comment: btw if you put it as an answer I can accept it